# How do I create this input field in Rails using form helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

So this is how I want the output to look:

```
<input id="f_name" type="text" value="First Name" required class="clearField curved" /> <br />
```

This is the form helper for the entire form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

I am just not quite sure how to stitch them both together, and get the input fields to be generated like that above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
<%= f.text_field :f_name, :value => 'First Name', :class => 'clearField curved'  %>
```

Edit: I can't mark it answered for another 2 days. So please don't tell me to mark it answered before then.

Thanks :)